# How do i set up a webcam server for HTTP?

Tags: 11.04, webcam, webserver

There used to be a package webcam-server, but it is no longer there. I would like to be able to view the picture from a Logitech USB webcam in a browser in a different computer in the same network. I have an apache server set up for something else, so port 80 is used.
note: the webcam definitely works with my computer; I can view it with other programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use VLC to capture and stream using all built in tools from the (imba) player:

Have a look here on how to set it up: http://wiki.videolan.org/Simple_Stream_VLC_to_Website

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I used the [package for karmic](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/karmic/+source/webcam-server/0.50-3) and it worked fine using the [Hacktivision tutorial](http://hacktivision.com/index.php/2009/06/16/setting-up-an-ubuntu-webcam-server).

EDIT: redid this now a year later - used the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I wanted to stream webcam from one computer to another in the same home network. I figured out I could just `ssh -X 192.168.1.76` and then start cheese

Comment: Can you offer some more detail, such as how to view the webcam in a browser as the OP describes?